# How many copies were created using an enum static variable

Tags: java, enums

I have enum class

```
public enum CommandEnum {       

    ADD_ITEM {
        {
            this.command = new AddItemCommand();
        }
    };

    protected Command command;

    public Command getCurrentCommand() {
        return command;
    }
}
```

And class which try to get particular command

```
CommandEnum currentState = CommandEnum.valueOf(action.toUpperCase());
current = currentState.getCurrentCommand();
```

And how many copies was created of class `AddItemCommand` if I called this command 4 times for example?

Comment: also `command` should be `final` in this case. In fact I'd argue that all fields of an enum should be `final`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have more than 1 command that's why not.

Comment: @Ray: how's that a problem? I assume you don't have more than 1 command *per enum value*. Or put differently: the `command` of an enum value will probably not change during it's lifetime, right? Maybe you're confusing `static` with `final` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum constants are public static final, so you will get the only one object every time. It's very easy to discover it yourself.